# How to bundle js with .so file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly, ffi, rollupjs

I have a cross-language program written in JS and C.
Here is my code

Host side:

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const myLibrary = ffi.Library('/root/ffi/js/lib.so', {
    'myfunction': ['int', ['int', 'int']]
  });
const result = myLibrary.myfunction(3, 4);
console.log(result);
```

Guest side:

```
int myfunction(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Obviously, it can be successfully executed on node.js. However, when I was trying to compile it into WebAssembly by utilizing Javy, it did not work, and I found out that Javy
did not support this and some suggested using transpilers like rollup to integrate the whole programs into one single JS. I've been reading about the tutorial but I'm not sure if it is feasible for dynamic linking. So I am seeking useful tools or some simple examples.Thanks in advance!